# Custom Conference Room in fusionPBX

Tags: freeswitch, pbx, fusionpbx

I have two issues going on

1. I want to create a conference room that calls an external number as soon as anyone joins the room,
   if the external call fails, the user should be directed to another fixed conference room.
2. I want another conference room that keeps playing a hold music,
   stays on mute no matter how many people join the room and the music should keep playing.

For the first one I created a new conference room, and modified it's xml in dialplan manager but it doesn't seem to work, the new xml is:

```
<extension name="MagicRoom" continue="" uuid="my_uuid">    

<condition field="destination_number" expression="^999$">        

<!-- Initiate an external call through the gateway -->        
<action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/sip.easybell.de/+491234xxxxxx"/>        
<!-- Join the caller to the conference room -->        
<action application="conference" data="999@my_ip@default+flags{''}"/>    

</condition>    

<!-- Add a fallback condition -->    
<condition field="${hangup_cause}" expression="NORMAL_CLEARING">      
  
<!-- If the call wasn't answered, route to another fixed room -->       
 <action application="conference" data="1100@my_ip@default+flags{''}"/>    

</condition>
 
</extension>
```

For the second point I'm using some custom fs_cli codes that is not proper and efficient. I think there's a better way to do this via XML.